# access to param config of another plugin jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins

Hy everyone,
I create a plugin in jquery from the scratch.
So i can do this without any conflit:

```
$('#some_id').myplugin({
    param1:'hello',
    param2:'world',
    idassociated:'other_id'
});

$('#other_id').myplugin({
    param1:'hello',
    param2:'world',
    idassociated:'some_id'
});
```

In the implementation code of the myplugin() i need to:

1. save the param of the `associatedID`
2. reset the plugin;
3. modify one param;
4. reinitialize `myplugin` with the new param;

In code:

```
    // 1 I have no idea
    $('#'+option.idassociated).myplugin('destroy'); // 2
    // 3 i have no idea and it depends from the point 1
    $('#other_id').myplugin({
        // 4 newparam
    });
```

In a few words I would like to know how to access the param instance of a plugin inside another the plugin.

Comment: If This can be useful, I solve this problem using the function .data() of jQuery.  https://api.jquery.com/data/